# How to center a cell horizontally and vertically?

Tags: vertical-alignment, multirow

I just have a question.
I do have the impression that s21 (and also s22, s23, s24) is not exactly in the middle of the lines "Falls Spieler 1 'schiessen' wählt, wähle 'schiessen'." and "Falls Spieler 1 'passen' wählt, wähle 'passen'."
How can I center s21 (and also s22, s23, s24) horizontally and vertically? I hope you see what I mean. Thank you for your help!!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage{csquotes}             

\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb} 

\usepackage{multirow,array} 
\usepackage{arydshln}         

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l|l}

\multirow{2}{10mm}{$s_{21}$} & Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
& Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{10mm}{$s_{22}$} & Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
& Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{10mm}{$s_{23}$} & Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
& Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
\hline

\multirow{2}{10mm}{$s_{24}$} & Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
& Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is not complete. In compilation I get error `\textcurrency` is not available in T1 coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For centering you need to make two changes in your code:

- first column type should be `c`
- for `multirow` use `\multirow{2}*{...}` instead `\multirow{2}{10mm}{`

Since I can not compile your original MWE, I comment parts which doing troubles. SO I get the following result:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage{array,multirow}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c|l}
\multirow{2}*{$s_{21}$} 
    &   Falls Spieler 1 \\    %\enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
    &   Falls Spieler 1 \\    %\enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
\hline
\multirow{2}*{$s_{22}$} 
    &   Falls Spieler 1 \\    %\enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
    &   Falls Spieler 1 \\    %\enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
\hline
\multirow{2}*{$s_{23}$} 
    &   Falls Spieler 1 \\    %\enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
    &   Falls Spieler 1 \\    %\enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
\hline
\multirow{2}*{$s_{24}$} 
    &   Falls Spieler 1 \\    %\enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
    &   Falls Spieler 1 \\    %\enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without `multirow`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}c<{$}|m{0.55\linewidth}}\hline
  s_{21} &   Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle 
  \enquote*{schiessen}\newline
             Falls Spieler 1 \\\hline
  s_{22} &   Falls Spieler 1 \newline
             Falls Spieler 1 \\   \hline
  s_{23} &   Falls Spieler 1 \newline 
             Falls Spieler 1 \\  \hline
  s_{24} &   Falls Spieler 1 \newline
             Falls Spieler 1 \\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You also might use the `\makecell` command, which allows for line breaks inside cells I took the liberty to slightly improve your table (in my opinion) with a thicker vertical rule and increasing `\arraystretch`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{a4paper, top=25mm, left=25mm, right=25mm, bottom=20mm, headsep=10mm, footskip=12mm}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{array, makecell}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \renewcommand{\cellalign}{lc}\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
  \begin{tabular}{ >{$}c<{$}!{\vrule width 1pt}l}

    s_{21} & \makecell{Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
    Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. }\\
    \hline

    s_{22} & \makecell{Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}. \\
    Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}.} \\
    \hline

    s_{23} & \makecell{ Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
    Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}.} \\
    \hline

    s_{24} & \makecell{Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{schiessen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{passen}. \\
    Falls Spieler 1 \enquote*{passen} wählt, wähle \enquote*{schiessen}.} \\

  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]